# Google Analytic Filter not verifiying

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I am setting up a custom exclude filter in Google Analytics doing this:

```
(4webmasters|best-seo-offer|buttons-for-your-website)\.[org|net|com]+
```

However when i click on verify, it says "This filter would not have changed your data. Either the filter configuration is incorrect, or the set of sampled data is too small."

When i run it through a [regexr checker](http://regexr.com/3b1op) it works. What am i doing wrong, if anything?

Comment: `\.[org|net|com]+` should be `\.(org|net|com)`.

Comment: @minitech that you for the reply. i made the change and it still won't verify.

Comment: Does it work if you try it with only one domain?

Comment: @Geoffrey: Did you try `(4webmasters|best-seo-offer|buttons-for-your-website)\.(org|net|com)`? Note there should be no `+` at the end.

Comment: @stribizhev tried it without the +, still won't verify. thank you for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 things to consider for the filter verification on Google Analytics,

***First*** - The **filter configuration:** You should use **Campaign source** as *filter field* (don't use referral) and the expression which in your case seems right, although you can simplify it.

This should be enough `4webmasters|best-seo-offer|buttons-for-your-website`

***Second*** - The filter verification just **takes a small sample of your data**, the previous 7 days, not including the present day. So if there is no record in those 7 days of any of them, it won't work.

***Third*** -  If you **try to verify with the filter previously saved**, GA will consider that you are verifying a new filter with the same configuration and since it already exists, you will get the message that it won't change your data.